# Razor Nest Elements TwitterBootstrapMVC5

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

How do you nest HTML elements using Razor?

Take this simple HTML for example

```
<label class="input">
    <i class="icon-prepend fa fa-user"></i>
    <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First name">
</label>
```

What would the equivalent to this be in Razor? For whoever thought this is too broad. I basically want to register @Html.Label() then go on and set child attributes for it which will include an icon and and textbox.

Is it even possible to do what I'm trying to achieve with razor?

It will create something like this

[image]

I tried to figure it out but failed badly. This is the best I got.

```
<label class="input">
    @Html.Bootstrap().Icon("icon-prepend fa fa-user")
    @Html.Bootstrap().TextBoxFor("fname", htmlattributes: new { placeholder = "First name" })
</label>
```

I was hoping to create the label in razor too.

Comment: The only 'out of the box helper' that is applicable for this is `@Html.TextBoxFor()` which would create the `<input type="text" ... />` element. You could create a custom html helper extension method (say) `@Html.TwitterTextBoxFor(m => m.fname)` which would render that html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a [custom HTML helper](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs). The output of the HTML helper will be what @CarlosAraujo suggests:

```
<label class="input">
    <i class="icon-prepend fa fa-user"></i>
    @Html.TextBoxFor("fname", htmlattributes: new { placeholder = "First name" })
</label>
```

You call it something like this:

```
@Html.MyCustomAwesomeTextBoxFor(...)
```

In this way you can encapsulate and re-use this component anywhere in your code.

Comment: I like this approach, you can obviously pass a bunch of parameters in too right? Or perhaps the whole `@Html.TextboxFor()`

Comment: you don't need to pass the whole '@Html.TextboxFor()', you should put that code inside your new custom HTML helper. And yes, you can pass the parameter that you need (probably just the name of the input).

Comment: Cool, Just thinking of reuability for other components like drop downs etc. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @ShaneVanWyk glad to help. Please select this or any other answer as the selected one if they helped you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
<label class="input">
    <i class="icon-prepend fa fa-user"></i>
    @Html.TextBoxFor("fname", htmlattributes: new { placeholder = "First name" })
</label>
```

Comment: So that is the closest id be able to get to using razor? So basically just wrapping the razor textbox function in a label item.